# Erlang function for()?

Tags: for-loop, time, erlang

From my understanding Erlang doesn't have the capabilities to do a for loop. However in this code snippet it uses the function for() in it. I don't really understand this for() function so any help is apprechiated.

```
-module(helloworld). 
-export([max/1,start/0]). 

max(N) -> 
   Max = erlang:system_info(process_limit), 
   io:format("Maximum allowed processes:~p~n" ,[Max]), 

   statistics(runtime), 
   statistics(wall_clock), 

   L = for(1, N, fun() -> spawn(fun() -> wait() end) end), 
   {_, Time1} = statistics(runtime),
   {_, Time2} = statistics(wall_clock),
   lists:foreach(fun(Pid) -> Pid ! die end, L),

   U1 = Time1 * 1000 / N, 
   U2 = Time2 * 1000 / N, 
   io:format("Process spawn time=~p (~p) microseconds~n" , [U1, U2]).

wait() ->
   receive 
      die -> void 
   end. 

for(N, N, F) -> [F()]; 
for(I, N, F) -> [F()|for(I+1, N, F)]. 

start()->
   max(1000), 
   max(100000).
```

Also what's the difference in run time and wall_clock in Erlang? I believe that wallclock is based off computers clock while runtime is based off of some sort of ticks in Erlang? I may be wrong though

Answer (score 5):

> I don't really understand this for() function so any help is apprechiated.

Rename the function xyz().  Now, does it make sense?

```
xyz(N, N, F) -> [F()]; 
xyz(I, N, F) -> [F()|xyz(I+1, N, F)].
```

The first clause of the `xyz()` function looks for a 1st and 2nd argument that are identical `(N, N...)`.  If the first two arguments are identical, then `xyz()` returns a list containing the return value of calling the 3rd argument.

The second clause of the xyz() function will match when the first two arguments are different `(I, N, ...)`.  In that case, the third argument is called and it's return value is the head of a list, with the tail of the list being a recursive call to the `xyz()` function, where the first argument is incremented.

So, let's try a simple example:

```
-module(f1).
-compile(export_all).

show() ->
   hello.


xyz(End, End, F) -> [F()]; 
xyz(Start, End, F) -> [F()|xyz(Start+1, End, F)].

test() ->
    xyz(0, 5, fun show/0).
```

In the shell:

```
5> c(f1).    
f1.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,f1}

6> f1:test().
[hello,hello,hello,hello,hello,hello]
```

And here is another example:

```
for(End, End) ->
    io:format("~w~n", [End]); 
for(Start, End) -> 
    io:format("~w~n", [Start]),
    for(Start+1, End).


test() ->
    for(0, 5).
```

In the shell:

```
12> c(f1).    
f1.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,f1}

13> f1:test().
0
1
2
3
4
5
ok
14>
```

Comment: Ahh, I do see! It's actually just a recursive way to implement a for loop. I feel silly for being confused now. Thank you for the quick pointer!

Comment: @Alex.Smith, Sure.  Basically, you write your own for-loops in erlang using recursion--and tailor the loops to your specific needs.  It looks like you are studying Joe Armstrong's "Programming Erlang" book.  If you want to compare your exercise answers to mine, see here:  https://github.com/7stud/Programming-Erlang-Exercises-Solutions-Answers

Comment: Excuse me, can you please explain why we can't swap patterns in the function ?
I don't get why it isn't working :
xyz(I, N, F) -> [F()|xyz(I+1, N, F)];
xyz(N, N, F) -> [F()].

Comment: @aleshka-batman, In your example, the parameter variables I, N, F will match any three arguments that xyz() is called with, including when the argument bound to I is equal to the argument bound to N, so erlang never evaluates the second function clause.  To get your example to work, you would have to add a guard:  `xyz(I, N, F) when I /= N -> ...`.

Comment: ...Erlang always attempts to match the function clauses in the order they are written, so the order of function clauses in erlang is important.  The order can be used to your advantage, e.g. by writing the `xyz(N,N,F)` and then not having to use guards for the second clause--erlang will only evaluate the second clause when the first two arguments are not equal.  Here's a little test: does the order of the function clauses matter for the function definition: `f(2) -> hello; f(X) -> goodbye.`

Comment: @7stud thanks, understood! In your example above patterns can't be swapped . If we do so , second pattern can't be reached.